# Mysql sum by two date by different and missing and new

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql query sum TOTAL by two dates by different and missing and new
GROUP BY NAME

```
10/10/2016  xx  10
10/10/2016  xx  15
10/10/2016  yy  15
10/10/2016  yy  45
10/10/2016  zz  25
10/10/2016  zz  5
10/10/2016  xx  5
10/11/2016  xx  15
10/11/2016  zz  25
10/11/2016  zz  5
10/11/2016  xx  45
10/11/2016  aa  45
```

i want this result

```
name    10/10/2016  10/11/2016  DIFF
+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+
aa      NULL        45          45
xx      30          60          30
yy      60          NULL        -60
zz      30          30          0
```

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (`date` date NOT NULL,`name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,`total` int(10) NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`date`, `name`, `total`) VALUES
('2016-10-10', 'xx', 10),('2016-10-10', 'xx', 15),('2016-10-10', 'yy', 15),('2016-10-10', 'yy', 45),('2016-10-10', 'zz', 25),('2016-10-10', 'zz', 5),
('2016-10-10', 'xx', 5),('2016-10-11', 'xx', 15),('2016-10-11', 'zz', 25),('2016-10-11', 'zz', 5),('2016-10-11', 'xx', 45),('2016-10-11', 'aa', 45);
```

Comment: It's easier (for me) to understand if you just keep the same yyyy-mm-dd pattern throughout

Comment: its show system default format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only have two dates in the query, you should be able to do a regular pivot query here.  There is one trick below.  In your expected output you want `NULL` to appear if a given `name` has no entries for a given `date`.  But in the difference column you want to treat that entry as being zero.  I implemented this by adding an `ELSE` condition which uses zero when a given name/date be absent.

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2016-10-10' THEN total END) AS 10_10_2016,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2016-10-11' THEN total END) AS 10_11_2016,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2016-10-11' THEN total ELSE 0 END) -
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2016-10-10' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS DIFF
FROM test
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Error SUM(CASE WHE' at line 4

Comment: if i modify with three dates what i changes made? i want learn it

Comment: Thanks Mr.Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how you want to compute the `DIFF` column in the case of three dates.

Comment: i understand Answer i also add data3 and used sum with between dates
works fine

Comment: Glad I could help you out.

Comment: if i test this more previous date names also showing 
i test only two dates name only 
but result show all names ??

Comment: You might want to ask a new question, and reference this one.  We could end up with a very long message tag here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125526/discussion-between-ashok-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,IFNULL(data1,0)-IFNULL(data2,0) FROM(
SELECT  `date`,`name`,
        MAX(IF(`date` = '2016-10-10',tot, NULL)) data1,
        MAX(IF(`date` ='2016-10-11',tot, NULL)) data2
FROM    (SELECT `date`,`name`,SUM(total) AS tot FROM test GROUP BY `name`,`date`) AS tab
GROUP   BY `name`)  AS t
```